# How can I generate lags of data nested in multiple columns?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

My goal is to calculate growth rates for age groups that are nested in spatial units over time. The data frame I am working with is structured like this (but much larger):

```
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(Time = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 Region = rep(c("A", "A", "B", "B"),3),
                 Age = rep(c(1,2), 6),
                 No_Persons = round(rnorm(12, mean = 10),0))
```

Within each category in `Region`, I need to get the change in `No_Persons` from one year to another (`Time`) and between `Age` groups 1 and 2. So basically the operation would be `Age2_Time2` / `Age1_Time1`. I tried achieving my goal using various `lag`-functions as well as `data.table::shift` but couldn't get it to work. For example, I though this would give me the desired results, but it only spits out `NAs`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>%
  mutate(Ratio = No_Persons / dplyr::lag(No_Persons,
                                      n = 1,
                                      order_by = "Age"))
```

I get the right results by using `pivot_wider` and then manually calculating growth rates by working with the columns, like this:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Age", values_from = "No_Persons") %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  mutate(Ratio = `2` / dplyr::lag(`1`, order_by = Time))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Region [2]
   Time Region   `1`   `2`  Quote
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 A          9    10 NA    
2     1 B         11     8 NA    
3     2 A         10    11  1.22 
4     2 B          9     9  0.818
5     3 A          9     9  0.9  
6     3 B         10     9  1
```

However, since the original data set has many more age groups, this becomes tedious and prone to error. I'd much prefer a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Updated Answer

From your comment, I reconstruct the minimum data set `df` with 3 time points, 2 regions and 3 age groups.

```
set.seed(1234)
time.number = 3
region.number = 2
age.number = 3
total.number = time.number * region.number * age.number
df <-
  data.frame(
    Time = rep(1:time.number, each = region.number * age.number),
    Region = rep(LETTERS[1:region.number], each = age.number),
    Age = rep(seq(1, age.number), region.number),
    No_Persons = round(rnorm(total.number, mean = 10), 0)
  )
df
```

The following solution should also applied to your real data.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# set df as data.table
setDT(df)

# calculate the number from real data
age.number <- df[,Age] %>% unique() %>% length()
region.number <- df[,Region] %>% unique() %>% length()

df[,.(V1=.SD[1:age.number-1,No_Persons],
      V2=.SD[2:age.number,No_Persons]),
   by = .(Time,Region)][,Radio:=V2/lag(V1,region.number)][]
```

Result:

```
   Time Region V1 V2    Radio
 1:    1      A  9 10       NA
 2:    1      A 10 11       NA
 3:    1      B  8 10 1.111111
 4:    1      B 10 11 1.100000
 5:    2      A  9  9 1.125000
 6:    2      A  9  9 0.900000
 7:    2      B  9 10 1.111111
 8:    2      B 10  9 1.000000
 9:    3      A  9 10 1.111111
10:    3      A 10 11 1.100000
11:    3      B 10  9 1.000000
12:    3      B  9  9 0.900000
```

### Previous Answer

I'm not sure if this is the result you want, but it can really get the right results.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(V1 = No_Persons[seq(1,.N,2)],
             V2 = No_Persons[seq(2,.N,2)]
            ),
          by = .(Time,Region)][,Radio:=V2/lag(V1,2)]
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to work. I dont't quite get what the code does, though, specifically this part: `V1 = No_Persons[seq(1,.N,2)], V2 = No_Persons[seq(2,.N,2)]` Would you be so kind and elaborate?

Comment: It extracts the odd and even row of the df which corresponds to 1 and 2 of yours.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The fact the data are structured in terms of even/odd is an artifact of me trying to provide a generalizable example. My real data has random numbers in both age groups of `No_Persons`. I will edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Your solution still works, so I must have misunderstood the explanation. It doesn't generalize to my real data though, since I have many more age groups.

Comment: @tifu I’m not clear what the many age groups means. Can you provide at least two age group as an example?

Comment: In the context of the provided data, you can imagine it like this: `Age = rep(c(1,44), 6)` So for each expression of `Region` (around 400 in the real data) and `Year` (10), I have information on persons aged 1 through 44. Thank you for taking the time to help out!

Comment: Sorry, it's still not very clear to imagine the more age groups. However, I just try to read your  question, I guess I now understand your data structure.  I construct the example data set with `set.seed(1234)
time.number = 2
region.number = 2
age.number = 3
total.number = time.number * region.number * age.number
data.frame(Time = rep(1:time.number,each = region.number * age.number),
           Region = rep(LETTERS[1:region.number],each = age.number),
           Age = rep(seq(1,age.number),region.number),
           No_Persons = round(rnorm(total.number, mean = 10),0))`, right?

Comment: It's a minimum data set for 2 time points, 2 regions and 3 age groups. Is this similar  with your real data?