# Referencing previous / next column in call to mutate()

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data looks like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Time = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 Region = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
                 Age_1 = round(rnorm(6, mean = 10),0),
                 Age_2 = round(rnorm(6, mean = 10),0),
                 Age_3 = round(rnorm(6, mean = 10),0),
                 Age_4 = round(rnorm(6, mean = 10),0),
                 Age_5 = round(rnorm(6, mean = 10),0))
```

I need to generate ratios of population change for each region and point in time. For instance, `Ratio_2` for `Time == 2` would be `Age_2` (at `Time == 2`) / `Age_1` (at `Time == 1`), grouped by `Region`. I could do this manually by typing:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>%
  mutate(Ratio_2 = Age_2 / dplyr::lag(Age_1, order_by = Time),
         Ratio_3 = Age_3 / dplyr::lag(Age_2, order_by = Time),
         Ratio_4 = Age_4 / dplyr::lag(Age_3, order_by = Time),
         Ratio_5 = Age_5 / dplyr::lag(Age_4, order_by = Time))

df
# A tibble: 6 x 11
# Groups:   Region [2]
   Time Region Age_1 Age_2 Age_3 Age_4 Age_5 Ratio_2 Ratio_3 Ratio_4 Ratio_5
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 A         11     8     9     9    10  NA       NA     NA       NA   
2     1 B         10     9    10    10    11  NA       NA     NA       NA   
3     2 A          9    10     9     8    12   0.909    1.12   0.889    1.33
4     2 B          9    10     9     9     9   1        1      0.9      0.9 
5     3 A          8    11     9     9    12   1.22     0.9    1        1.5 
6     3 B          9     9     9     9     9   1        0.9    1        1
```

Since my original data has lots of age groups, this procedure involves lots of manual coding. A programmatic solution in my mind could look something like this:

```
df %>%
   group_by(Region) %>%
   mutate(across(4:7, ~ . / dplyr::lag(.[?], order_by = Time), .names="Ratio_{.col}"))
```

The part containing `dplyr::lag(.[?])` needs to reference the previous column in the data frame relative to `.` but I haven't found a method for doing so.

**Note**: This question is related to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640250/how-can-i-generate-lags-of-data-nested-in-multiple-columns/66642420?noredirect=1#comment117823360_66642420) from yesterday, in which I was trying to solve the problem at hand with the data being in long format. Doing it in wide format is a different question though, which is why I opened this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Region) %>% 
    mutate(across(matches('^Age_[2-5]$'),
       ~ ./lag(get(str_replace(cur_column(), '\\d+',
       as.character(readr::parse_number(cur_column())-1))), order_by = Time ),
       .names = "Ratio_{.col}" )) %>%
    ungroup
```

---

Or it can be done in a simplified  way

```
library(purrr)
df[str_c('Region_', 2:5)] <-  map2(df[4:7], df[3:6], 
          ~ .x/lag(.y, order_by = df$Time))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. This is really outstanding!

Comment: Great stuff, thank you @akrun. I figured the simplest solution would involve ´purrr´, but this code I would not have been able to come up with myself

Comment: @tifu you don't need a package for that.  i.e. it can be done in `base R` as well, i.e. `df[paste0('Region_', 2:5]) <- Map(function(x, y) x/lag(y, order_by = df$Time), df[4:7], df[3:6])` (using only the `lag` from `tidyr`